# Create new record depending option set field value

Tags: dynamics-crm, crm

I have custom entity with a few required fields. One of them is the `record type` field, that can have value `internal`, `external type 1`, `external type 2`. There is also a lot of `Subgrids` and fields and each of them is visible just for one of `record type` values.

Is there a way to make a few forms for one entity, with some basic form containing just the `record type` field, that would redirect me to the selected form depending on selected `record type`. That form  would have just the components required by the `record type`. And if there is a way to do that, is it the best practice, or it would be better to keep everything on the same form and set visibility using JavaScript?

Comment: Did you tried yourself? If so please share your attempt. If not, please try yourself and share the attempt.

Comment: I have tried to use Dialog with "Create Record" step, but it didin't let me choose the form I want to  create, it opens main form by default

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depends on the form complexity. If there is a not a lot happening on the form, show/hide tabs would be the best option. But if there are a lot of fields and a lot of logic it is better to use different forms and use form selector's [Navigate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg309560.aspx#BKMK_navigate) property to force the users to a different form based on the selection. Keeps things much cleaner.

If the form has unsaved values you might also either have to do a [Save](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn481607.aspx#BKMK_dataSave) and navigate.

```
function recordType_OnChange() {
    Xrm.Page.data.save().then(function() {
        Xrm.Page.ui.formSelector.items.get(formId).navigate(); //switch formId based on record type value
    }, function(error) {
        console.log(error);
    });
}
```